# Python/SQLite3 raise function error

Tags: python, triggers, sqlite, raise

I've got small problem with RAISE function in my trigger. This is my SQLite code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckingDate
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.Start_date > NEW.End_date
BEGIN
RAISE(ABORT, 'End_date must be in the future');
END;
```

`Start_date` and `end_date` are `SMALLDATETIME` and `Start_date` is the result of `datetime('now')`.

I run it in my python 2.7 program with all other sql script by `sqlite3.complete_statement()` and it gives `Syntax Error near RAISE`. Can someone tell me why? I tried `ABORT`, `ROLLBACK`, instead of `ABORT` or `SELECT CASE` or `WHEN THEN` in my trigger but it still gives error;

Comment: I *think* you need to use a `SELECT RAISE()` since `RAISE()` is a SQL function and `CREATE TRIGGER` requires one of insert, update, delete or select to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAISE()` is a SQL function, you'll need to use it as part of a statement; `TRIGGER`s only allow for `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `SELECT` statements; use it in a `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckingDate
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.Start_date > NEW.End_date
BEGIN
SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'End_date must be in the future');
END;
```

This triggers the error correctly:

```
sqlite> insert into mytable values ('2030-1-1 20:20:20', datetime('now'));
Error: End_date must be in the future
```

Comment: I found few tutorials but I didn't know about that. Thank you very much:)